# How to integrate Airflow python operator with Datadog for monitoring of the process

Tags: python, airflow, datadog

Is it possible to integrate Airflow with Datadog in the sense of monitoring the logic within PythonOperator?

For example, assume the following PythonOperator and python callback -

```
def rand_task(**context):
    time = round(time.time() * 1000)
    random.seed(time)
    rand = random.random()

rand_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="rand_task",
    python_callable=rand_func,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

I want to create a monitoring mechanism in Datadog on the value of `rand` variable.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you what to do with the data, you can send both [logs](http://%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/#send-logs) and [metrics](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics) from your Python callback to Datadog via HTTP. If you want to create an actionable monitor, you probably want to use a metric.

You could also explore the [`SimpleHttpOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/operators.html) to avoid adding additional dependencies.